# Retrieve email from MS Exchange (O365) using EWS Managed API

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Requirement: To connect to `MicroSoft Exchange 2013` from a WinForms Application `(.Net Framework 4.0, C#)` and retrieve email(s) thereby saving attachment(s) to local drive. Without using `Outlook` or `VBA` to retrieve emails.

The ideal solution is to use Exchange Web Services Managed API from the .Net program and retrieve email(s) using appropriate methods.

However, the Exchange server in this scenario is the cloud based Office365 and the .Net program would be developed from a local Visual Studio 2010 IDE. It appears to be the practice that Cloud based (Office365) Exchange server is accessed from programs based in Azure development platform and local MicroSoft Exchange Server is accessed from programs based in local Visual Studio IDE.

So I wanted to check whether I can actually connect to an Office365 MS Exchange mailbox using EWS Managed API from a program developed in a locally hosted Visual Studio IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. If you want to try it yourself, download EWSEditor from CodePlex.com and try it out.